Impossible to communicate with a deployed contract
I'm pretty new to blockchain, but I'd like to understand it more.
I'd like to communicate with a deployed contract using Hardhat in order to solve a CTF challenge on HackTheBox.
The challenge gives us the private key, the address of the target contract and our address, as this:
    "PrivateKey": "0x654e7e1612c9b1416ecff46e3077525cb89e8c371ee04b4879c5021ba8710277",
    "Address": "0x2d4090E13274c57EaCc80Cb3adb998ba159688A0",
    "TargetAddress": "0xc02b5fbf014f1BCb52b8040A884321100D18e68f",
    "setupAddress": "0xC44150B47c7B6984f299c82219eCf6af67c60ab1"

and an RPC endpoint such as:
http://83.136.253.251:32150/rpc

and I'd like to be able to communicate with the contract in the same way I can use Foundry commands such as:
cast call $ADDRESS_TARGET "lifePoints()(bytes32)" --rpc-url $RPC_URL

for instance... So:
I type npx hardhat console and

> const hre = require("hardhat");
undefined
> const { ethers } = require("ethers");
undefined
> var provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider('http://83.136.253.251:32150/rpc');
undefined
> var deployedContract = await hre.ethers.getContractAt("Rivals", "0xc02b5fbf014f1BCb52b8040A884321100D18e68f")

and at this point I receive this error message:
Uncaught HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "Rivals" not found.
    at Artifacts._handleWrongArtifactForContractName (/home/fab/Downloads/blockchain_honor_among_thieves/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:721:11)
    at Artifacts._getArtifactPathFromFiles (/home/fab/Downloads/blockchain_honor_among_thieves/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:852:19)
    at Artifacts._getArtifactPath (/home/fab/Downloads/blockchain_honor_among_thieves/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:516:21)
    at Artifacts.readArtifact (/home/fab/Downloads/blockchain_honor_among_thieves/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:71:26)
    at getContractFactory (/home/fab/Downloads/blockchain_honor_among_thieves/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:107:22)
    at REPL4:1:43
    at node:repl:641:29

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd be grateful.
Thanx in advance,
Fab
